# Gjiten: "No dicfiles specified! Set your preferences first."

Tags: 15.10, dictionary

Everytime I install Ubuntu, I also install [Gjiten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gjiten), so it has been a dozen times already, and it is always as simple as installing the package with `apt-get install`. In particular, I never had to manually download nor configure any particular dictionary file.

But today I reinstalled the same 15.10 on the same laptop, and it behaved differently, surprisingly. For some reason it asks for a dictionary that it had never asked for the other times:

[image: No dicfiles specified! Set your preferences first]

> No dicfiles specified! Set your preferences first

I just noticed that I have packages `edict` and `kanjidict` installed, by the way. They are dependencies of [gjiten](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/gjiten).

How to avoid this unnecessary difficulty?

Comment: I tried it really quickly in a VM running 15.10, and it installed without a problem.  You might need to remove and reinstall  the application.

Answer (score 0):

Gjiten needs dictionary files to function. You will need the kanjidic dictionary file for kanji lookups for KanjiDic and other dictionary files for the word dictionary in edict format.

Install them using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install enamdict edict kanjidicic
```

Source: http://gjiten.sourceforge.net/gjiten-doc/x102.html

Comment: edict kanjidic were already installed. I just installed enamdict and restarted gjiten, same problem.